# How can I take advantage of a banded, unsymmetric sparse matrix in R in terms of storage and computation speed?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Say I have a banded, unsymmetric sparse matrix like the one below, created using the R Matrix package:

```
x = Matrix(matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1), 4, 4), sparse = TRUE)
print(x)
1 . . .
. 1 1 .
. 1 . 1
. . . 1
```

1. Are there any preexisting packages I can use to store such a matrix more efficiently due to its banded nature? I will be working with matrices with thousands of rows/columns, so the sparse matrix classes from Matrix save lots of storage there, but I'm hoping to go a step further due to its banded structure. I am thinking of storing the diagonals and off-diagonals of the matrix as a quick fix, but perhaps there is a smarter solution available iin R.
2. Is there currently an implementation of matrix multiplication in R (or Rcpp or Fortran) that can perform faster matrix multiplications with these banded matrices compared to what is available for regular sparse matrices?

Comment: will they always be tridiagonal and binary?  How sparse are the diagonals themselves (i.e., should you be storing sparse vectors or bit patterns?)

Comment: Good question, neither of those need be true. I'm taking a feature set to be used as training for SVM, and permute the rows and columns with reverse-cuthill mckee reordering to get them to be smaller bandwidth. So in practice, they won't usually be tridiagonal and binary. In terms of sparsity, ideally anything with >50% zero entries should be accommodated

Comment: How 'banded' would they be, i.e. how many/what fraction of the off-diagonals will have non-zero elements? I suspect the answer to your question is going to be "no"; there are a few different sparse-matrix packages (`Matrix`, obviously, `spam`, `SparseM`, `grep("sparse",rownames(available.packages()), value=TRUE,ignore.case=TRUE)` but I don't see much other than column/row-oriented indexing. BLAS/LAPACK have some support for tridiagonal matrices, but I don't see anything much more general than that ...

Comment: It depends on the matrix, but I've seen matrices with more than 90% non-zero off-diagonals. Still an improvement on the unbanded matrix

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Isn't the standard BLAS-style diagonal sparse matrix implemented in [Matrix::bandSparse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/1.2-18/topics/bandSparse)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, bandSparse only returns a Csparse matrix, which is generic and not just for banded matrices. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Yeah you're right, I've never tried using it, just seen it in the matrix namespace. Good to know what it produces. I've used the BLAS-style diagonal matrix with intel's MKL and it works great, but I don't think there's an R wrapper for it - you'd have to use Rcpp.